# How to run StartTimer in all items of ListView separately in Xamarin Forms

Tags: listview, xamarin.forms

I am trying to run the clock for lets say 5 cities, like each city in each cell of the listview and clock(local time) running besides city name. (Screenshot attached below)

I am getting the local time of the city using offset value of that city.

And for the clock to move I used StartTimer, so that the time will change for every second.

Currently I am getting the offsetValue as zero there and so getting the UTC time there for all the cities as same.

I want all the cities with the local time displaying beside city name and the clock must move for every second.

Any help will be appreciated .. 
Thanks in advance.

[Sample screenshot of cities with respective clocks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6o093.png)

```
List<OffsetItems> items = new List<OffsetItems>();
        items.Add(new OffsetItems() { CityName = "Hyderabad", Offset = 5.5 });
        items.Add(new OffsetItems() { CityName = "London", Offset = 1 });
        items.Add(new OffsetItems() { CityName = "Tokyo", Offset = 9 });
        items.Add(new OffsetItems() { CityName = "New York", Offset = -5 });
        items.Add(new OffsetItems() { CityName = "Dubai", Offset = 4 });


        ListView lv = new ListView
        {
            SeparatorVisibility = SeparatorVisibility.None,
            ItemsSource = items,

            ItemTemplate = new DataTemplate(() =>
            {

                Label cityL = new Label()
                {
                    TextColor = Color.Black,
                    HorizontalTextAlignment = TextAlignment.Start,
                    FontSize = Device.GetNamedSize(NamedSize.Small, new Label())
                };
                Label timeL = new Label()
                {
                    TextColor = Color.Black,
                    HorizontalTextAlignment = TextAlignment.Center,
                    FontSize = Device.GetNamedSize(NamedSize.Small, new Label())
                };
                cityL.SetBinding<OffsetItems>(Label.TextProperty, indexer => indexer.CityName);

                Label ll = new Label();
                Device.StartTimer(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1), () => {

                    ll.SetBinding<OffsetItems>(Label.TextProperty, indexer => indexer.Offset);
                    double offsetValue = Convert.ToDouble(ll.Text);

                    timeL.Text = DateTime.UtcNow.AddHours(offsetValue).ToString("hh:mm:ss tt, ddd dd-MMM-yyyy");
                    return true; 
                });

                return new ViewCell
                {
                    View = new StackLayout
                    {
                        Orientation = StackOrientation.Horizontal,
                        Children =
                            {
                            cityL,
                            timeL
                        }
                    }
                };
            })
        };

        Content = new StackLayout
        {
            Children = {
                lv
            }
        };
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have added the code for what Alessandro has mentioned and that is how it should be done.

```
class OffsetItems : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private double _offset;
        private string _time;
        private string _cityName;

        public string CityName
        {
            get { return _cityName; }
            internal set
            {
                _cityName = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("CityName");
            }
        }

        public string Time
        {
            get { return _time; }
            internal set
            {
                _time = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("Time");
            }
        }

        public double Offset
        {
            get { return _offset; }
            internal set
            {
                _offset = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("Offset");
            }
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }

    public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
    {
        ObservableCollection<OffsetItems> Items = new ObservableCollection<OffsetItems>();

        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            Items.Add(new OffsetItems() { CityName = "Hyderabad", Offset = 5.5 });
            Items.Add(new OffsetItems() { CityName = "London", Offset = 1 });
            Items.Add(new OffsetItems() { CityName = "Tokyo", Offset = 9 });
            Items.Add(new OffsetItems() { CityName = "New York", Offset = -5 });
            Items.Add(new OffsetItems() { CityName = "Dubai", Offset = 4 });

            var lv = new ListView
            {
                ItemsSource = Items,
                SeparatorVisibility = SeparatorVisibility.None,
                ItemTemplate = new DataTemplate(() =>
                {

                    Label cityL = new Label()
                    {
                        TextColor = Color.Black,
                        HorizontalTextAlignment = TextAlignment.Start,
                        FontSize = Device.GetNamedSize(NamedSize.Small, new Label())
                    };
                    Label timeL = new Label()
                    {
                        TextColor = Color.Black,
                        HorizontalTextAlignment = TextAlignment.Center,
                        FontSize = Device.GetNamedSize(NamedSize.Small, new Label())
                    };
                    cityL.SetBinding<OffsetItems>(Label.TextProperty, indexer => indexer.CityName);
                    timeL.SetBinding<OffsetItems>(Label.TextProperty, indexer => indexer.Time, BindingMode.OneWay);

                    Label ll = new Label();

                    return new ViewCell
                    {
                        View = new StackLayout
                        {
                            Orientation = StackOrientation.Horizontal,
                            Children =
                            {
                                cityL,
                                timeL
                            }
                        }
                    };
                })
            };

            Content = new StackLayout
            {
                Children = {
                    lv
                }
            };
        }

        protected override void OnAppearing()
        {
            base.OnAppearing();
            Device.StartTimer(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1), () =>
            {
                Items.ForEach(row => row.Time = DateTime.UtcNow.AddHours(row.Offset)
                    .ToString("hh:mm:ss tt, ddd dd-MMM-yyyy"));
                return true;
            });
        }
    }
```

*Foreach is an extension which i have it in private lib. Hope this code helps

Answer (score 0):

I think you should not have a StartTimer in your template. You should have a StartTimer (for example) in OnAppearing method.

When the StartTimer event rises, you should change a "Time" property you should have in your Model (changing the "Time" property to ALL items in your ObservableCollection... you should not use a "List"). Bind this "Time" property to your "timeL" field. Now your timeL fields should update automatically if you implement INotifyPropertyChanged.

Comment: Thanks for your help @Alessandro. I have given an up vote but its not taking as I have less reputation.